# Matching certain words (Pattern) in a text with Java

Tags: java, text, design-patterns, extract, matching

i have got a text. Within the text there are several words all beginning with a unique identifier "KEY" whereby the words look like this "KEY_1_This_is_a_key". The words can be within a sentence ("this is KEY_1_This_is_a_key etc"), can be comma separated "KEY_1_This_is_a_key, KEY_2_This_is_a_key" or between brakets "this is a (KEY_1_This_is_a_key)".

Is there a bullet proof way to extract all of the words beginning with "KEY"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is that any special character on the last character of your word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    String s = "KEY_1_This_is_a_key, KEY_2_This_is_a_key";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(KEY.+?)\\b").matcher(s);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Comment: maybe you should accept it as the right answer if it worked :)